# Show battery percentage in status bar/notch

Tags: iphone, ipad, battery

As it is possible on lastest iPhones, I want to put my battery level IN the status bar.
This is  what I want it to be :

[image: on my iPhone]

This is what it is:

[image: on my iPad]

Is it possible on iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.2? If possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can turn the percentage on or off, the location it appears is fixed.